# How do I get ASP.NET controls which visible set to false to collapse the area between controls?

Tags: asp.net

I  have some controls on the page which are Invisible on page load.

But according to user input that many number of controls should get visible. I have done this.

But my page looks little bit dirty because sometimes many controls are invisible. So lot of space is lost.

How can I manage that?

Is there any particular option in Visual Studio 2008 to perform this so that the lost space is adjusted automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you setting the visibility of the controls?  There is a difference between visibility setting and display setting.

This link explains it well: [Visibility vs Display](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638)

If you a specifically talking about ASP.NET controls... Keep in mind that setting Visible="false" for any control causes ASP.NET to not render the control at all, so it's not too useful if you need to toggle the visibility on the client side.

Comment: There is not property of Visibility="false"  it would be Visible="false"

Comment: heh... Good catch.  That's what I get for coding in an auto-completion IDE all these years.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible for you to wrap your Invisible controls in an `Panel` control or a `UserControl`.  That way you can make your entire Panel Control invisible, hiding the whitespace with it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you toggling the visibility of the controls? If you set the Visibility of a server control to `false` in Page_Load, it will not render at all and nor will any space it might have taken up. If however, you use Javascript to toggle visibility, make sure to switch the `display` CSS property of controls, not the `visibility` property.

The answer also depends on your HTML markup.